# diff between way of declaring list

Tags: apex

Wanted to know the difference between these two line

```
List<Int_No__c> outField = new List<Int_No__c>([select Id,Name, from Int_No__c where  Dir__c ='Out']);
```

and the second way of  declaring

```
List <Int_No__c> outField = [select Id,Name, from Int_No__c where  Dir__c ='Out'];
```

It seems to me that they are same . Thanks in advance for looking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**They are not the same.**

You don't need to do this,

```
List<Int_No__c > outField = new List<Int_No__c >([select Id,Name, from Int_No__c where Dir__c ='Out']);// consumes more cpu power
```

You should always use the below method with a query.

```
List<Int_No__c > outField = [select Id,Name, from Int_No__c where Int_No__c ='Out'];
```

> The constructor of the List class `List<T>(listToCopy)` creates a new instance of the List class by
>   copying the elements from the specified list. T is the data type of
>   the elements in both lists and can be any data type.

IF you want to copy some list to new instance then you can use like below

```
List<Integer> ls1 = new List<Integer>();
ls1.add(1);
ls1.add(2);
// Create a list based on an existing one
List<Integer> ls2 = new List<Integer>(ls1);
// ls2 elements are copied from ls1
System.debug(ls2);// DEBUG|(1, 2)
```

[Refer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm)

Comment: thanks a lot Rahul ,its pretty clear now

Comment: most welcome!!!

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I use the array syntax of `[]` for the type (that is syntactic sugar over list) as I think it makes this common-case code more symmetrical on the left and right sides:

```
Int_No__c[] outField = [select Id,Name, from Int_No__c where  Dir__c ='Out'];
```

Comment: thanks a lot Keith yup will use this now on as this will make the code symmetric